# Scriptaculous Autocomplete: Returns a List of Links, Want to Have Link Clicked Instead of Autofilling the Input Field

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, scriptaculous

I am working with scriptaculous' autocomplete.  I am returning an unordered list but each element is a link.  For example,

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="link1">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="link2">Link 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you scroll down the list using the arrow keys and hit enter,  Autocomplete will only grab the text instead of activating the link, as it is designed to do.  What I want, is for autocomplete to go to the new page.  Is there any way to do this, and I have no problem editing the scriptaculous code to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the afterUpdateElement, as in the example on http://madrobby.github.com/scriptaculous/ajax-autocompleter/

```
  new Ajax.Autocompleter("autocomplete", "autocomplete_choices", "/url/on/server", {
    afterUpdateElement : function(text, li){
       document.location.href = "http://mypage.com/page/" + li.id;
    }
  });
```